# call addEventListener inside addEventListener callback function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am a student studying react.
There's a problem with the component I'm making right now.
What I am trying to make is a scroll-type picker similar to the link below.
https://codepen.io/gnauhca/pen/JrdpZZ

In the process of implementing this, there is a problem in registering and removing eventListener in eventListener.

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

function Scroller() {
  const array = [170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180];
  const [dragEventHistory, setDragEventHistory] = useState([]);
  const [dragEventStart, setDragEventStart] = useState(null);

  const scrollerContainer = useRef();
  const scrollerList = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const moveList = (clientY) => {
      const difference = Number(dragEventStart) - Number(clientY);
      scrollerList.current.style.transform = `translate3d(0, -${difference}px, 0)`;
    };

    const onMouseMoveEventHandler = (e) => {
      console.log(e);
      e.preventDefault();
      moveList(e.clientY);
    };

    const onMouseDownEventHandler = (e) => {
      console.log(e);
      e.preventDefault();
      setDragEventStart(e.clientY);
      scrollerContainer.current.addEventListener(
        "mousemove",
        onMouseMoveEventHandler
      );
    };

    const onMouseUpEventHandler = (e) => {
      console.log(e);
      e.preventDefault();
      scrollerContainer.current.removeEventListener(
        "mousemove",
        onMouseMoveEventHandler
      );
    };

    scrollerContainer.current.addEventListener(
      "mousedown",
      onMouseDownEventHandler
    );
    scrollerContainer.current.addEventListener(
      "mouseup",
      onMouseUpEventHandler
    );

    return () => {
      scrollerContainer.current.removeEventListener(
        "mousedown",
        onMouseDownEventHandler
      );
      scrollerContainer.current.removeEventListener(
        "mouseup",
        onMouseUpEventHandler
      );
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className="scroller-container"
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        overflow: "hidden",
        width: 200,
        height: 250,
      }}
      ref={scrollerContainer}
      // onTouchStart={onTouchStartEventHandler}
      // onTouchEnd={onTouchEndEventHandler}
    >
      <ul className="scroller-list" ref={scrollerList}>
        {array.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li
              key={index}
              style={{
                width: 200,
                height: 50,
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                backgroundColor: "orange",
                fontSize: 30,
              }}
            >
              {item}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Scroller;
```

If I define functions without using useEffect, depending on the change of 'dragEventStart' state, the callback function registered as an event cannot be removed in the process of component rerendering.
If I define functions in useEffect, removeEventListener function can point the callback function that is same with addEventListener function's callback. But dragEventStart state can't be changed. However, if dragEventStart is included in the dependency of useEffect, it becomes the same as when useEffect is not used.

How can I solve this problem? I need help!!

Comment: Why would you ever use `addEventListener` in react instead of the props designed for that?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski
Hello! onMouseDown and onMouseUp can be registered by react props, but my real problem is  an onMouseMove event! onMouseMove event should be registered if onMouseDown is ON, and removed if onMouseUp is ON. onMouseMove event's callback function has a state(dragEventStart), so problem is occured!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of declaring `dragEventStart` a React state variable and relying on proper enclosures of values, I suggest converting it to a React ref that can be mutated at will.

Also, instead of continually adding/removing event listeners just add the mouse down|up|move listeners once when the component mounts, and remove them in the returned `useEffect` hook cleanup function.

To make the UX a bit better for the user the mouse up and move event listeners should be attached to the `window` object so drags don't get "stuck" if the user isn't over the `scrollerContainer` element when releasing the mouse button.

Example:

```
function Scroller() {
  ...
  const [dragEventHistory, setDragEventHistory] = useState([]);
  const dragEventStartRef = useRef(null);

  const scrollerContainer = useRef();
  const scrollerList = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const moveList = (clientY) => {
      // Only handle move if drag is started
      if (dragEventStartRef.current) {
        const difference = Number(dragEventStartRef.current) - Number(clientY);
        scrollerList.current.style.transform = `translate3d(0, -${difference}px, 0)`;
      }
    };

    const onMouseMoveEventHandler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      moveList(e.clientY);
    };

    const onMouseDownEventHandler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      dragEventStartRef.current = e.clientY;
    };

    const onMouseUpEventHandler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      dragEventStartRef.current = null;
    };

    scrollerContainer.current.addEventListener(
      "mousedown",
      onMouseDownEventHandler
    );
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUpEventHandler);
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMoveEventHandler);

    return () => {
      scrollerContainer.current.removeEventListener(
        "mousedown",
        onMouseDownEventHandler
      );
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUpEventHandler);
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMoveEventHandler);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: I think this is overcomplicating things too – I doubt there'll be much of a performance issue if the handlers are registered on the div all the time, but the mousedown/mouseup handlers change a ref-boxed value that changes whether the mouse move handler does anything...

Comment: In fact, in order for this to work correctly, the mouse up handler would need to be on `window`, so letting go of the button when the mouse is not over the element doesn't keep it "stuck" scrolling around...

Comment: @AKX Ah, yeah... that's what I was thinking as well as I found it odd to attach the mouse down/up to a specific DOMNode.

Comment: @AKX You were right, I needed to take another look at the logic. There's no need to continually add/remove any of the listeners/handlers, the move handler should only run any logic if a drag gesture has been initiated.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question!!
You guys are my heroes!!!!